# session not shared between two server

Tags: java, security, jsp, web-applications, session-cookies

i  have big trouble with my application that web-application(jsp,java,servlet)  landed between  two server cause 
there is load-sharing between server but unfortunately session not maintaining  between server now i am checking checking after login if session is there than ok otherwise i am taking all credential from url (visible encoded url with same key if somebody remember url then big mess  ) obviously its not secure at all ,SO how we can resolve this problame at application level please guide me.......

Comment: does your load balancer support sticky sessions (so that the same session always goes to the same server)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two options:

- **sticky session** - once some user hits one server, load balancer makes sure she will always use the exact same server.
- **session replication** - every change in HTTP session is migrated to another nodde in the cluster. Load balancer remains unaffected.

Both approaches are configuration only, no changes to your application are required.

Comment: +1 No changes to the application, but maybe more than just configuration. Could involve some infrastructure upgrade.

Comment: Note that for session replication to work, you usually need to make sure you only add Serializable attributes to your session. Otherwise, the session itself can't be serialized and passed between servers. You should only be putting Serializable stuff in your session even if you aren't using replication, but it's something people often get away with; might require some changes to your application.