# How can i cluster a spring mvc application?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, distributed-computing

I have a web application written with spring on a jetty server. because of load balancing i have to replicate http sessions and spring-security contexts over the web servers.

Can anybody point me at a working example how to make this possible?

the mvc controllers are part of spring-security-oauth2 so i have limited ability to influence them and jetty is a prerequisite for our environment. for most of the data and caching we will use infinispan.

I could not find any current information how tu cluster with spring, so i'm grateful for every help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. What is stateless, scales out automatically (like most of Spring beans and controllers)
2. What is shared, must be replicated or all instances in the cluster must share on

   1. HTTP sessions must be replicated. If they are, Spring security (which stores security context in the session will *just work*
   2. Database will just work - you'll either just use one or replicate it as well
   3. Infinispan should handle replication of in-memory caches

Providing that you only store `Serializable` items in HTTP session and in caches, clustering your application should just work. Watch out for synchronized code (should locks be distributed?) and stateful beans.

## See also

- [session not shared between two server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598919)

Comment: i am aware of those things, but i can not find any example/documentation whatsoever that explains how to configure spring/jetty to do session replication.

Comment: @Laures: For what I see Jetty (at least 6) does not support session replication out-of-the-box. You must use some solution on top of it, like Hazelcast, Gigaspace, JGroups, Terracotta, database... See: http://webtide.intalio.com/2011/08/nosql-sessions-with-jetty7-and-jetty8/ Also consider switching to Tomcat, which supports clustering out-of-the-box. From Spring framework perspective, there is nothing you have to change (except your design, if required).

Comment: great. i kind of expected i would have to create some infinispan/hazelcast based spring sesseion-store bean and configure it somewhere in the mvc namespace. now i can do that directly in jetty as switching to tomcat is probably not an option.

Comment: @Laures: you don't have to do anything in Spring, just implement this Jetty session store and use your HTTP servlet session like you used to.

Answer (score 4):

Though I am late but I think spring-session could be a potential candidate. Look out the solution in another Stackoverflow question.

[Session replication with Spring session and Hazelcast over Tomcat/Jetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27513673/spring-boot-with-hazelcast-and-tomcat)

[Spring-session Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5)

Comment: well when new solutions are available, new suggestions are always welcome